# Passive Infrared (PIR) Motion Sensor

Tags: sensor, raspberry-pi, wireless, proximity-sensor, pir

I want to have the PIR Motion Sensor:
https://www.adafruit.com/product/189

Used to turn on a light whenever it detects motion.

Simple enough, but would it be possible to have this done wirelessly?

I.E. PIR Motion Sensor detects motion, sends a single high to a transmitter, signal is sent to receiver, receiver has output signal to blink an LED.

Note: The transmitter and receiver will only be about 5 feet away from each other, so hopefully all of this can be low power.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

(Raspberry Pi is tagged because I wasn't sure if one would be required to implement what I want)

Comment: Why not as long as the battery lasts long enough.

Comment: Yes the concept sounds good. Now if I could just get some solid advice as to which components to use exactly, that'd be great.

Comment: I use those PIRs and ESP8266s for just that task. You will want to power the ESP through the PIR, using a FET. You can use wifi if you set a PIR delay of >4 seconds (wifi takes a while to connect), but recommend ESPNOW instead of wifi. It can boot from cold and send a message within 250ms to another always-on ESP8266 running ESPNOW in the same channel. That always-on one blinks the LED upon getting an ESPNOW event from the PIR-connected one.

Comment: It ends up being very slow compared to motion sensors using burst IR reflections. e.g. driveway lamps but then can tell the difference between a moving mammal and a moving bush or branch nearby on a windy day. But I liked when my 200MHz antenna return loss sensor detected people moving 10m away instantly.

Comment: @dandavis - I think you mean *"power the PIR through the ESP"*...

Comment: @Bort: no, the ESP stays off 99.99% of the time with ESP-NOW, allowing zero-current standby yet no noticeable delay upon activation (200ms), like a garage door opener. most PIRs only draw about 100ua, so its more effective to have that always-on than the MCU.

Comment: @dandavis - My bad. I was thinking the ESP sleeps in a low-current mode and then the PIR wakes the ESP. I'll have to research ESP-NOW some more.

Comment: WiFi sounds like overkill to me. If the transmitter and receiver are within line of sight, you might want to consider using an IR LED and [IR remote receiver](https://www.adafruit.com/product/157).

Answer (score 0):

I am working on something similar and for Private wireless and secure network you should use Xbee device https://store.ncd.io/product/zigbee-mesh-xbee-pro-long-range-wireless-mesh-communications-module-with-integrated-antenna/ connection which is easy to be compatible with sensor as Router and transmits the wireless signal, which will be received by another Zigbee device connected to arduino and acts as coordinator.

Hope this will be helpful for your making wireless connection between sensor and Development boards

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one option might be to use an [ESP8622 board](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2821) and a way to [interface with a PIC sensor](https://www.instructables.com/Interface-PIR-Sensor-With-NodeMCU/)